# How to disable "add to cart" in multiple woocommerce categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the add to cart button from multiple woocommerce categories. I've placed this code in my functions.php file:

```
//function for deleting ....
function remove_product_description_add_cart_button(){
    global $product;

    // Set HERE your category ID, slug or name (or an array)
    $category = 'categoryslug';

    //Remove Add to Cart button from product description of product with id 1234    
    if ( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product->id ) )
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

}
add_action('wp','remove_product_description_add_cart_button');
```

But my problem is that it only removes add to cart from the one category specified. I've tried modifying the code to allow multiple categories and nothing I've done has worked. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: If this helps: All I want to do is only allow items from a specific category to be purchased and all other categories to have the "add to cart" and paypal buttons hidden.

Comment: Did you try this condition `has_term( array($category1, $category2) , 'product_cat', $product->id )`? If product has category1 or category2, then remove action